# Integrate Compass With Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps, compass-geolocation

i m working on Android Maps and i need to Add Compass functionality in it that is When I click on Compass Button it shows separate compass. 
Can any one guide me the Right direction or refrence me any tutorial. I need to add Compass seperatly 
thanks in Advance for reading and Replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scenario in My Cass is To Use Separately use The Compass When click on Compass Button 
it Will Show

- Distance from Current Location(My Location) to the Destination location
- Compass
- Compass Head Towards North Direction 
  So to achieve all these I've used the following approach 
  hope this will help anyone who has the same scenario as I have

The Code Snippet of my Class That will get Distance between two points around the globe and show image as Compass with head towards north direction

```
public class MapController extends MapActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    public static GeoPoint Mypoint, MapPoint;
    double km, meter;
    public static int kmInDec, meterInDec;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer, mField;
    Location myLoc, mapLoc;
    double myLat, myLong, mapLat, mapLong;

    public static double lat, lng;
    public static double mylat = Double.parseDouble(Constants.DEVICE_OBJ.lat);//31.567615d;

    public static double mylon = Double.parseDouble(Constants.DEVICE_OBJ.lng);//74.360962d;
    com.google.android.maps.MapController mapController;
    public static boolean enabled = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);
        Log.v(Constants.TAG, "In Map Controller");

        fetchUI();
    }

    public void fetchUI() {
        myLoc = new Location("Test");
        mapLoc = new Location("Test");
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mField = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        myLat = (31.567615 * 1e6) / 1E6;
        myLong = (74.360962d * 1e6) / 1E6;
        mapLat = (MapPoint.getLatitudeE6()) / 1E6;
        mapLong = (MapPoint.getLongitudeE6()) / 1E6;
        myLoc.setLatitude(31.567615);
        myLoc.setLongitude(74.360962);
        mapLoc.setLatitude(mapLat);
        mapLoc.setLongitude(mapLong);
    }


    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mField, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


    ///Method to calculate the Distance between 2 Geo Points aroud the Globe
    public double CalculationByDistance(GeoPoint StartP, GeoPoint EndP) {
        double lat1 = StartP.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
        double lat2 = EndP.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
        double lon1 = StartP.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
        double lon2 = EndP.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                        Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        double valueResult = Radius * c;
        double km = valueResult / 1;
        DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
        kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
        meter = valueResult % 1000;
        meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
        Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "  KM  " + kmInDec + " Meter   " + meterInDec);

        return Radius * c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (myLoc == null) return;

        float azimuth = event.values[0];
        float baseAzimuth = azimuth;

        GeomagneticField geoField = new GeomagneticField(Double
                .valueOf(myLoc.getLatitude()).floatValue(), Double
                .valueOf(myLoc.getLongitude()).floatValue(),
                Double.valueOf(myLoc.getAltitude()).floatValue(),
                System.currentTimeMillis());

        azimuth -= geoField.getDeclination(); // converts magnetic north into true north

        // Store the bearingTo in the bearTo variable
        float bearTo = myLoc.bearingTo(mapLoc);

        // If the bearTo is smaller than 0, add 360 to get the rotation clockwise.
        if (bearTo < 0) {
            bearTo = bearTo + 360;
        }

        //This is where we choose to point it
        float direction = bearTo - azimuth;

        // If the direction is smaller than 0, add 360 to get the rotation clockwise.
        if (direction < 0) {
            direction = direction + 360;
        }

        rotateImageView(compasView, R.drawable.app_icon, direction);

        //Set the field
        String bearingText = "N";

        if ((360 >= baseAzimuth && baseAzimuth >= 337.5) || (0 <= baseAzimuth && baseAzimuth <= 22.5))
            bearingText = "N";
        else if (baseAzimuth > 22.5 && baseAzimuth < 67.5) bearingText = "NE";
        else if (baseAzimuth >= 67.5 && baseAzimuth <= 112.5) bearingText = "E";
        else if (baseAzimuth > 112.5 && baseAzimuth < 157.5) bearingText = "SE";
        else if (baseAzimuth >= 157.5 && baseAzimuth <= 202.5) bearingText = "S";
        else if (baseAzimuth > 202.5 && baseAzimuth < 247.5) bearingText = "SW";
        else if (baseAzimuth >= 247.5 && baseAzimuth <= 292.5) bearingText = "W";
        else if (baseAzimuth > 292.5 && baseAzimuth < 337.5) bearingText = "NW";
        else bearingText = "?";

        Distance.setText(kmInDec + "  Km " + " " + meterInDec + " m");
    }
    ////This is the method to Show the Image as Compass

    private void rotateImageView(ImageView imageView, int drawable, float rotate) {

        // Decode the drawable into a bitmap
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                drawable);

        // Get the width/height of the drawable
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth(), height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();

        // Initialize a new Matrix
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        // Decide on how much to rotate
        rotate = rotate % 360;

        // Actually rotate the image
        matrix.postRotate(rotate, width, height);

        // recreate the new Bitmap via a couple conditions
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
        //BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable( rotatedBitmap );

        //imageView.setImageBitmap( rotatedBitmap );
        imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), rotatedBitmap));
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this depend on your physical location on the globe?

Answer (score 0):

use this guide:
[Google Maps Tutorial](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mappingDemo.html)

search for compass, try launching a new activity with your needs when pressing on the compass (an overlay)

anyway, the tutorial is very comprehensive, I believe it will solve most of your needs =).

Comment: this is not what i want but yes i manipulate it with my own way

Comment: write it as the answer then, help other people who might get to this post